# Submit só executa uma vez

Tags: javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Função que ao clicar no botão, irá fazer.
    $("#logarsist").click(function(){
        var usuario = $("#usera").val();
        var password = $("#pass").val();

        if(usuario == ''){
            $("#formulariousuario").html("Campo Obrigatório*");
            setTimeout(function(){$("#formulariousuario").hide();}, 6000);};

        if(password == ''){
            $("#formulariopassword").html("Campo Obrigatório*");
            setTimeout(function(){$("#formulariopassword").hide();}, 6000);};

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Não entendi sua pergunta. Você quer que o seu submit só seja executado uma vez ou ele só está executando uma única fez? Caso a resposta seja a primeira alternativa, basta alterar ".click" por ".one" na terceira linha. Caso não seja isso, verificou se o console exibe alguma mensagem de erro?

Comment: ele só executa uma vez, não tem erros no console .

Comment: na verdade ele executa mais de uma vez, só que as id com as mensagens só aparecem uma unica vez

Comment: Não acontece porque, depois da primeira vez, elas já estão hide(); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pela descrição que me deu em sua pergunta, o código está sendo executado, porém você esqueceu de exibir novamente as divs que ocultou.

Acredito que isso resolve o seu problema:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#logarsist").click(function()
    {
        var usuario = $("#usera").val();
        var password = $("#pass").val();

        if(usuario == '')
        {
            $("#formulariousuario").html("Campo Obrigatório*");
            $("#formulariousuario").show(); // também pode usar o fadeIn()
            setTimeout(function()
            {
                $("#formulariousuario").hide(); // também pode usar o fadeOut()
            }, 6000);
        };

        if(password == '')
        {
            $("#formulariopassword").html("Campo Obrigatório*");
            $("#formulariopassword").show();

            setTimeout(function()
            {
                $("#formulariopassword").hide();
            }, 6000);
        };

        return false;
    });
});
```

Com um pouco mais de adaptação no seu código você consegue alguns resultados melhores. Veja:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var timeout = null;

    $("#logarsist").click(function()
    {
        var usuario = $("#usera").val();
        var password = $("#pass").val();

        if(usuario == '')
        {
            $("#formulariousuario").html("Campo Obrigatório*").show();
        };

        if(password == '')
        {
            $("#formulariopassword").html("Campo Obrigatório*").show();
        };

        // Cancele o timeout para evitar que ele oculte suas divs em momentos inesperados
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(function()
        {
            // Acrescente a classe "error" nas divs que deseja exibir as mensagens de erro.
            $('.error').hide();

        }, 6000);

        // Você só deve retornar false se o form tiver erros ou for chamar outra função para realizar o envio do formulário.
        return false;
    });
});
```

Usando um seletor de classes e acrescentando a classe em seu HTML, você evita código desnecessário, e pode ter um tratamento mais unificado.

O JQuery também permite que você combine vários métodos em um único seletor, reduzindo o processamento de buscar novamente o elemento e reduzindo seu código.

Comment: agora eles aparecem e some em segundos :/

Comment: como vc me recomendaria para enviar esses dados para o php?